# User control events do not fire

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a problem with my events in a UserControl.

```
<UserControl x:Class="LatikeManager.Views.RoomManager_Item"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LatikeManager.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="170" d:DesignWidth="220" Width="200" Height="150" Background="Transparent" MouseLeftButtonUp="UserControl_MouseLeftButtonUp">

<!--<Border BorderBrush="{Binding BorderColor}" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top">-->

<Grid Name="gdContent" Width="200" Height="150" Background="Wheat">

    <Button Width="30" Height="30"></Button>

    </Grid>
<!--</Border>-->
```

the code behind :

```
public partial class RoomManager_Item : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public bool RoomManagerItemEventArgs { get; set; }

        public MyEventArgs(bool isSelected)
        {
            RoomManagerItemEventArgs = isSelected;
        }
    }

    public class OnlineEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public bool OnlineStateChanged { get; set; }

        public OnlineEventArgs(bool Connected)
        {
            OnlineStateChanged = Connected;
        }
    }

    #region //Events
    public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs args);
    public event MyEventHandler RoomManagerItem_SelectedChanged;

    public delegate void OnlineEventHandler(object sender, OnlineEventArgs args);
    public event OnlineEventHandler RoomManagerItem_OnlineChanged;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

    #region //Images
    private dynamic unknownStatus = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/Help-48.png", UriKind.Relative));
    private dynamic greenStatus = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/Ok-48.png", UriKind.Relative));
    private dynamic warningStatus = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/Error-48.png", UriKind.Relative));
    private dynamic errorStatus = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/Cancel-48.png", UriKind.Relative));

    private dynamic computerOnline = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/Workstation-50(2).png", UriKind.Relative));
    private dynamic computerOffline = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/Workstation-50.png", UriKind.Relative));

    private dynamic laptopOnline = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/Workstation-50(2).png", UriKind.Relative));
    private dynamic laptopOffline = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/Laptop-50.png", UriKind.Relative));

    public int wert = 0;
    #endregion              

    #region
    private ILatikeClient _ClientRef;
    public ILatikeClient ClientRef
    {
        get { return _ClientRef; }
        set
        {
            _ClientRef = value;
            if (RoomManagerItem_OnlineChanged != null)
                RoomManagerItem_OnlineChanged(this, new OnlineEventArgs(IsConnected));
        }
    }

    public bool IsConnected { get { return ClientRef != null; } }
    public RegisterInfo Info { get; set; }
    public List<Program> ProgramInfo { get; set; }
    public HardwareInfo HardwareInfo { get; set; }
    public dynamic SSDStateSource { get; set; }
    public DB.SYSTEM Rechner { get; set; }
    public dynamic ComputerOnlinePicture { get; set; }

    private bool _IsSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _IsSelected; }
        set
        {
            _IsSelected = value;
        }
    }

public RoomManager_Item(DB.SYSTEM rechner)
    {
        Rechner = rechner;
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void UserControl_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
        {
            IsSelected = !IsSelected;
        }
        else
        {
            IsSelected = true;
        }

        if (RoomManagerItem_SelectedChanged != null)
        {
            RoomManagerItem_SelectedChanged(this, new MyEventArgs(IsSelected));
        }
    }

}
```

I don't know why this isn't working, it did not fire anywhere in the usercontrol. No event does fire up, not even the click event of buttons and the button also not hovers.

In my code is an dispatcher, that works fine

```
new DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), DispatcherPriority.Normal,
(s, a) =>
{
    RefreshClientInfo(null, null);
},
Dispatcher);
```

…but I can not interact with that form in any way.

In addition the code to load the UC's to my Grid

```
private void Room_Changed(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ctxROOM.Count != 0)
            if (cbRooms.SelectedIndex != -1)
                if (CurrentRoom == "Übersicht")
                {
                    btnAllNoneEnabled = false;
                    gdDesign.RowDefinitions.Clear();
                    gdDesign.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
                    gdDesign.Children.Clear();
                    gdContent.Children.Clear();                        
                    var overviewRoom = ctxROOM.Select(p => p).ToList();//get all rooms
                    //checked any room on content 
                    foreach (DB.ROOM item in overviewRoom)
                    {
                        var overviewSystemRoom = ctxSYSTEM_ROOM.Where(p => p.room_name == item.room_name).ToList();
                        //if the room has Systems, create them
                        foreach (var checkContent in overviewSystemRoom)
                            if (checkContent != null)
                            {
                                gdContent.Children.Add(new RoomManager_RoomOverview(item, overviewSystemRoom, ctxSYSTEM));
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    btnAllNoneEnabled = true;
                    gdContent.Children.Clear();
                    var raum = ctxROOM.Single(p => p.room_name == CurrentRoom);
                    gdDesign.RowDefinitions.Clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < raum.room_rows; i++)
                    {
                        gdDesign.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()
                        {
                            Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star),
                            MinHeight = 152
                        });
                    }
                    gdDesign.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < raum.room_columns; i++)
                    {
                        gdDesign.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition()
                        {
                            Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star),
                            MinWidth = 202
                        });
                    }

                    gdDesign.Children.Clear();
                    for (int r = 0; r < raum.room_rows; r++)
                    {
                        for (int c = 0; c < raum.room_columns; c++)
                        {
                            RoomManager_Item item;
                            var system = ctxSYSTEM_ROOM.SingleOrDefault(p => p.row == r && p.column == c && p.room_name == CurrentRoom);
                            DB.SYSTEM systemVar = new DB.SYSTEM();

                            if (system != null)
                            {
                                systemVar = ctxSYSTEM.SingleOrDefault(p => p.description == system.system_description);
                                item = new RoomManager_Item(systemVar);
                                item.ContextMenu = ctxMenue;
                                item.RoomManagerItem_SelectedChanged += (s, b) =>
                                {
                                    //var roomSeats = _Ctx.ROOM.Select(p => p.room_name == CurrentRoom ? p.seats : 0);
                                    var selectedSystem = ctxSYSTEM_ROOM.SingleOrDefault(p => p.system_description == systemVar.description);
                                    roomItemsSelected[selectedSystem.row, selectedSystem.column] = b.RoomManagerItemEventArgs;
                                    if (b.RoomManagerItemEventArgs) count++;
                                    else count--;
                                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("btnAllNone"));
                                };
                                gdDesign.Children.Add(item);
                                Grid.SetRow(item, r);
                                Grid.SetColumn(item, c);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }
    }
```

This is the method where i get the number of UserControls i need and add them to my grid.

Comment: Have you tried PreviewMouse events?

Comment: Yes i tried, but no event triggers, instead of Usercontrol_Loaded

Comment: 2 other things to consider; 1) does your `UserControl` have an actual `Background` i.e. not null, 2) Are your `Border` or `Grid` control preventing the mouse events (try hooking up the event to the `Grid`).

Comment: the background is set in the UserControl_Loaded method, Adding the Event to Border or Grid does not fix the problem. Also it seems like the usercontrol is "disabled" because buttons i add to this control are not working (not even hover)

Comment: If your buttons are not showing hover then it probably means you have either something rendering on top or it is as you suggest and they are disabled (are they showing in the disabled state i.e. grey)? Can you supply the Xaml which renders the `UserControl`?

Comment: i just added the hole code in my question, can not find any problems

Comment: How do you add a RoomManager_Item to the UI? Can you supply the Xaml for that? Failing that you should check out Snoop, you can interrogate the UI and find what is topmost

Comment: i just added the code for that to my question. My Program is getting bigger and this is the first time i have that issue

Comment: I would suggest installing Snoop and interrogating your app

Comment: Thank you very much, the Problem was a ScrollViewer that catcht the MouseUp Event. Answer and i will mark it :)

Comment: Thanks I have added an answer. Glad it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there is clearly something blocking or handling the mouse events. I strongly suggest that you download [Snoop for WPF](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) this will allow you to interrogate the UI to see if anything is above your control and even monitor the mouse events to see what is handling them.